# Push notifications android parse.com or gcm?

Tags: android, database, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I have one database mysql , I need when i add one new a row on my database receive one notification who is the best for this and more simple gcm or parse.com ?

I am new on android world , so please explain to me step by step who is the best and why?

Comment: you can use Parse.com its simple cloud implementation

Comment: and work with my database ? without import  for parse.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try this way I'll help u..

Parse Notification in android
Step 1. Create account in parse and get application id and client id.

**Application.java**

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

 public Application() {
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();


 }
}
```

Follow [this link](http://saveen-android.blogspot.in/2015/02/parse-notification-in-android.html?m=0) for more details

Thats all hopefully somebody help this topic thanks....

Comment: And i can do it without import mydatabase to parse.com? can i use my server for this ?